# Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'wagmi.cache' exceeded the quota

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-query, wagmi

I am building a **Next.js** app that uses **wagmi** and **react-query**.

I had to upgrade **wagmi** from "**0.6.8**" to version "**0.12.10**" to get the walletConnect v2 connector.

Ever since I upgraded, I am getting the attached error in the console. It arises when I have used the app for a few minutes and have gone back and forth between some pages that fetch some data.

Error Message
[image: error message]

I tried clearing the **wagmi.cache** in local storage but that only solved the problem for a couple of days and after that, the problem reoccurred as the storage got filled again.

The queries array in the wagmi.cache gets filled with too many queries which leads to the limit being reached.

Comment: seems like wagmi uses the peristence plugin from react-query, but hasn't accounted for items being too large to fit into localstorage. React Query allows for error handling and retries in that case, but not sure if wagmi has impelemented or exposed those. Open an issue in wagmi.